# Issue with SQL Server Query store

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, sql-query-store

Few weeks back I did run an in-place upgrade from SQL Server 2016 to SQL Server 2017 CU 5 in one of our main environments. I used Slipstream upgrade so it was one shot. This is a 2 nodes shared storage FCI with single instance and 1 replica on a remote datacenter (so total 2 instances, 1 AG , several databases in the AG, async). The upgrade went mostly OK

The next step was to enable Query Store and Automatic Query Tuning in the most critical database (2 TB Data File, 100 GB Tr Log file, heavily loaded). That was one of the main purpose of the upgrade

Few days later I noticed that the transaction log usage for that DB was about 80% and growing. Log_reuse_wait_desc was ACTIVE_TRANSACTION

Running DBCC OPENTRAN and got below

> Transaction information for database 'MyDatabase'.
>
> Oldest active transaction:
>       SPID (server process ID): 62s
>       UID (user ID) : -1
>       Name          : QDS nested transaction
>       LSN           : (6017515:1461640:1)
>       Start time    : Apr  9 2018  3:01:06:073AM
>       SID           : 0x0 DBCC execution completed. If DBCC printed error messages, contact your system administrator.

And here is the session ID 62

> spid       kpid       blocked waittype             waittime
>   lastwaittype              waitresource     dbid      uid         cpu
>   physical_io         memusage              login_time
>   last_batch          ecid       open_tran          status   sid
>   hostname          program_name hostprocess       cmd       nt_domain
>   nt_username    net_address      net_library         loginame
>   context_info      sql_handle         stmt_start          stmt_end
>   request_id 62          -12076  21          0x0005 454        LCK_M_X
>   MD: database_id = 17 QDS_STATEMENT_STABILITY(qds_statement_key =
>   0xd1c26b6), lockPartitionId = 0
>
> 17          1            3857719             179918 0
>   2018-04-09 03:01:05.947              2018-04-09 03:01:05.947
>   0            1            background
>   0x0100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
>   QUERY STORE BACK
>   sa
>   0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
>   0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000        0            0
>   0

even trying to kill spid 62 is not allowed since it is saying "Only user processes can be killed." even when this is over spid 50

I am not able to do much besides seen the transaction log usage going up so I decided to disable automatic query tuning and query store

Disabling automatic query tuning was quick but not for Query Store. I did it using T-SQL . the statement ran for 3 hours doing nothing more than blocking all the system objects for that db. Transaction log usage was over 95%

disabling or cleaning QDS get blocked by this spid 62

do I cancelled the statement . Finally I restarted the instance and when it came back online I was able to disable QDS right away.

Any ideas ? Have you seen this before ?

Thanks
Regards

Javier Villegas

Comment: seems like something you should report on the SQL Server uservoice board rather than here.

Comment: I have seen this. I suspect it is QDS processing its async captures (as a worst case, perhaps days) after a large spike in queries that need to be persisted. Such a spike can happen when (as an example) a scalar function is called as a predicate against large table(s). I have more than one example of that poor practice being submitted to our SQL Servers. For us, a scalar function is being called in the low tens of million times. In addition to the QDS nested transaction blocking, for us the query store exceeds its max storage size.